# How can I cache headers with varnish 4?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am not able to find a way to do it. Can you help me with some code. I searched a lot on internet but wasn't able to find something.

Comment: Varnish caches both HTML and HTTP headers of a page. Thus your question makes little sense. Can you clarify?

Comment: I thought I had this problem but my problem is even bigger. I get Err_Connection_Refused after modifying the varnish default file. I have installed it properly. Varnish is on port 80 and apache on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

double check you have changed the backend port to 8080 also in default.vcl file.
Restart apache and varnish.
You can follow this blog post to ensure varnish is properly installed: https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/install-and-test-varnish-in-5-steps